# Jquery code shortening

Tags: jquery, short

I've written a small jquery code, but it looks very redundant and childish. Can anyone help shorten it or make more effecient?

Here's the code:

```
    // DIM The Light Effect 
   var dimlight  = $(".dimlight"),
   showlight = $(".showlight"),
   overlay   = $("#overlay")
   playerlive   = $("#player_live"),
   lightswitch   = $(".light_switch")   

       playerlive.mouseover(function(){

       lightswitch.show();
      });

       playerlive.mouseout(function(){

       lightswitch.hide();
      });

       dimlight.click(function(){

       overlay.fadeIn();
       dimlight.hide();
       showlight.show();
      });

      showlight.click(function(){
       overlay.fadeOut();
       dimlight.show();
       showlight.hide();
      });

      showlight.click(function(){
       overlay.fadeOut();
       dimlight.show();
       showlight.hide();
      });
```

Thx a lot already

Comment: You have `showlight.click(...)` twice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just do:

```
  $('.dimlight, .showlight').click(function(){
   if ($(this).hasClass('dimlight')) {
       overlay.fadeIn();
       dimlight.hide();
       showlight.show();
   } else {
       overlay.fadeOut();
       dimlight.show();
       showlight.hide();
   }
  });
```

Comment: One time it is `dimlight.show();`, the other time `dimlight.hide();`

Comment: hey common i am not spamming man.. you are much older in SOF and I hope you are aware that preferably best answer should be marked as accepted atleast for the help of future visitors.. they should not be misguided.

Comment: Let the community handle that. No need to 'spam' te comments. I said spamming, because you basically just posted the same (unnneeded) message twice.

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite the whole code as below:

```
$("#player_live").hover(function(){
    $(".light_switch").toggle();
});

var elems = $('.dimlight, .showlight');
elems.click(function(){
   elems.toggle();
   $("#overlay").fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Why not `$(".light_switch").toggle()`?

Comment: ofcourse that can be done but since that is on mouseover and mouseout, 2 different function, using show hide will avoid confusion.

Comment: I mean `$("#player_live").hover(function() { $(".light_switch").toggle(); });` - see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TVULe/)

Comment: Please note the when upgrading to jQuery 1.7+ you cannot use the shorthand `.hover()` when using `.on()`.

Comment: @PeeHaa can you explain? That's new to me.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Scratch that. I read it wrong. From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/): "Although strongly discouraged for new code, you may see the pseudo-event-name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.". It's about the pseudo event and not the function.

Comment: @PeeHaa cheers, no harm done. rajkumar - not my downvote, actually just realized I didn't upvote yet